# I want to limit (NOT ROUND) floating point numbers to a certain number in PYTHON,

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want floating numbers be limited for example to 8. When I run the below code it gives me 16 floating numbers. For example, `x=4` and `y=3`, it gives `1.3333333333333333`. How can I reduce the number of "3"s. NOTE: I DON'T WANT TO ROUND, JUST LIMIT "3"s.

```py
x=int(input())
y=int(input())
print(x/y)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that if you

- multiply the number by a power of 10
- convert the number to int  and
- at last divide the number by the power of 10

So the code:

```
def limit_num(num, limit):
    num = num * 10**limit
    num = int(num)
    num /= 10**limit
    return num

number = 4/3 # 1.3333333333333333

number = limit_num(number, 5)

print(number) # 1.33333
```

Or in one line:

```
def limit_num(num, limit):
    return (int(num * 10**limit) / 10**limit)
```

Answer (score -1):

round will not give you correct result if decimal digits are 999 types.
You should convert float to string and try

```
def truncate_float_decimal(float_num, truncate_to_digits):
  base_length = len(float_num.split('.')[0])+1
  base_length += truncate_to_digits
  return  float((float_num[:base_length]))

truncated_float = truncate_float_decimal("14.999992223",7)
print (truncated_float)
```

Comment: `a` is undefined, and even with that error corrected, this produces [wrong results](https://ideone.com/0Kcd0w) for floats large enough or small enough that the string representation is in scientific notation